# Run php function after user confirm

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have some code like this :

```
 <?php foreach ($vips as $vip) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $vip['id'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $vip['vip_name'] ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/editVip/<?php echo $vip['id'] ?>">Edit</a> / <a
                href="<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/deleteVip/<?php echo $vip['id'] ?>">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

I have two links called `Edit` and `Delete`. I want when user click on `Delete` link a confirm window appears with javascript and if user click on `ok` on that confirm window, then execute `deleteVip` method.
How can I have something like this ?
(I'm using `codeigniter` framework)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add confirmation in anchor tag itself;

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/deleteVip/<?php echo $vip['id']; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss=  confirm("are sure you want delete");
  
  if(ss==true)
    {
      alert("hi");
      return true;
      
      
      }
  else
    
    {
      alert("no");
      return fasle;
      
      }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete code..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to display a confirm box.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="myFunction();">Delete</a>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x;
    if (confirm("Are you want to delete ?!") == true) {
        x = "You pressed OK!";
    } else {
        x = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

on button click call this function

```
function Confirm(){
var txt;
var r = confirm("R u sure you want to delete this...!!!");
if (r == true) {
  return true
} else {
  return false
}
```

and in your button you have right like below

```
<input type="button" name="button" value="button" onclick="return Confirm();" />
```